# Race condition in ngrx effects with switchmap resulting slow performance

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I've one simple effect that make an GET request using Injected Angular service.

That request return JSON response ( 10 000 lines ).

```
  @Effect()
  effectExample$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(actions.ONE_EXAMPLE_REST_API_ACTION),
      switchMap((action: actions.OneExampleRestApiAction) => {
        console.time('timer');
        return this.service
          .getJsonResponse()
          .pipe(
            map((response) => {
              console.timeEnd('timer');
              return new actions.OneExampleRestApiActionSuccess(response);
            })
          );
      })
    );
```

As you can see I added 
console.time('timer');
console.timeEnd('timer');

And what is happening?

In console I'm getting that timer takes approximatelly between 15 - 20 seconds. It vary, while if I'm calling the same request that is called with getJsonResponse() using **POSTMAN** then requests always take between 2-3 seconds maximum.

```
getJsonResponse() {
return this.http
      .get(`http://example.com/getjson`);
}
```

What can be reason that it needs 15 - 20 seconds until map is executed or

```
return new actions.OneExampleRestApiActionSuccess(response);
```

Can it be because response is JSON object of 10000 lines so postman can handle it faster or ? I really don't have idea at the moment what is blocker from line:
**.getJsonResponse()**
to
**return new actions.OneExampleRestApiActionSuccess(response);**

because server needs as I said only 2-3 seconds to return response if I'm using postman.

Also in network tab for above request it shows execution time of 2 seconds, but apparently Angular or Effect needs 15 - 20 seconds to get to the **return new actions.OneExampleRestApiActionSuccess(response);**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting a race condition because of the switchMap. This is causing the delay that you see in the response time.
Here is a good [post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524) that you refer